# Issue with Spring Boot and Gradle: Jitpack requesting a module with an incorrect URL

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, jitpack

I am using Spring Boot version 3.1.0 and facing an issue while retrieving a module using jitpack. The URI that jitpack uses to retrieve the module appears to be incorrect which is causing the failure of the retrieval process. I would like to know how to resolve this issue.

This is the error I am facing:

```rb
Could not find GAuth-Spring-Security-Java-v0.0.1.jar (com.github.YangSiJun528:GAuth-Spring-Security-Java:v0.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jitpack.io/com/github/YangSiJun528/GAuth-Spring-Security-Java/v0.0.1/GAuth-Spring-Security-Java-v0.0.1.jar
```

Here is the correct URL for the module: https://jitpack.io/com/github/YangSiJun528/GAuth-Spring-Security-Java-v0.0.1.jar.

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

group = 'dev.yangsijun'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.GSM-MSG:GAuth-SDK-Java:v2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.YangSiJun528:GAuth-Spring-Security-Java:v0.0.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.